# How do I turn on javascript support on a PHP project in eclipse?

Tags: php, javascript, eclipse

Once a project has been created (PHP) is there any way to turn on javascript support for the project or would a new project have to be created? I would prefer not to create a new project.

Comment: What do you mean JavaScript support? You mean code completion?

Comment: From the Configure menu I have the option to convert the project to a JavaScript project however I still want this to be a PHP project with JavaScript support.

Comment: Thanks, I did turn this into a Javascript project, the project is quite large and doing so has impacted performance quite a lot, even on a relatively fast computer, on one occasion an out of memory error occurred (4gb ram). I wonder if I had selected javascript support for the php project on original setup instead, if that would of resulted in the same speed issue. I shall have to test this when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either create a new PHP project and tick the Javascript support checkbox, or from the Configure menu, there is the option to convert the project to a JavaScript project.